# Need more positive than negative current

Tags: power-supply, power, current, transformer, 12v

**My power supply collapses due to uneven positive and negative current draws.**

I need about 2A of +12VDC, 1A of +9VDC, and 0.5-1A of -12VDC in a design I’m working on. I’d like to avoid using multiple transformers if possible, so I’d like to use a 2x15VAC transformer with a centre tap, use a full-wave rectifier which should yield some +-21VDC, add 3300μF smoothimg capacitors, and scale the respective voltages down using stabilisers and/or zeners (or possibly voltage dividers).

The primary source is 230VAC, 50Hz.

**The problem is, when running my design through a simulator,** which may or may not be accurate and where I’m only able to use zeners, **the whole supply keels over because of the unequal current draws,** producing about -22VDC and only a few +VDCs. **How do I solve this?**

[image: Basic schematic]

I’ve tried inserting dummy loads on the negative side and cranking up the input voltage to compensate, but that didn’t turn out too well.

EDIT: As a newcomer here, my question might go through several edits to meet the forum’s requirements.

Comment: So, please show us a schematic of what you've currently designed, including the primary side(s) of your transformer(s) including voltage and frequency descriptions.

Comment: That power level is very high for a linear supply, you'd be making a nice little 35W room heater. Consider switching supplies. Zeners are inappropriate and should be off the table- suitable zener diodes are in the $50 range each and require large heat sinks. Thanks for adding the schematic but it does not illustrate the issue you attribute to unequal current draws.

Comment: That is a very crude and inefficient power supply.

Comment: Check the +12 V load, edit your question to clearly state the load resistances for 9 V, 12 V, and -12 V. Don't "black out" parts that might be crucial (1 Ω series resistor for the Z-diodes?!).

Comment: (Did you intend Axe Murderer?)